# Is there a way to place some impure code inside pure functions?

Tags: haskell, monads

`IO`, just like `Maybe`, is just an instance of `Monad`. On the other hand we have all data constructors for `Maybe` (`Just` and `Nothing`), but no constructors for `IO`. `Reader` and `Writer` do not export constructors too, they have functions, which return instance of this type (`reader` and `writer`) and more importantly `runReader` and `runWriter`, which unwrap computation result from Monad.

Is there a way to unwrap IO Monad? I would like to have pure function which do some impure IO computations under the hood. Currently I am able to do this with most of the Monads

I know one example of such tricky function: `Debug.Trace.trace`

Comment: You can use [`ST`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) for locally impure operations.

Comment: This is _precisely_ what the IO monad tries to prevent. All the impure effects are relegated inside the IO. Why on earth do you want to break that?

Comment: It definitely doesn't mean you can unwrap something because it's a `Monad`. Consider `data Proxy a = Proxy` (Note that there is no value "contained in" `Proxy` at all) which is a `Monad`.

Comment: You cannot unwrap `IO` *by design*, because its very purpose is to mark operations that are necessarily implemented by the compiler, not in Haskell code.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, `ST` is exactly what you're looking for. Running `IO` locally is against everything Haskell stands for.

Comment: It is far too hasty to say `ST` is what he's looking for.  While it is a good solution for many problems, he has yet to state a need and his one example was `trace` - certainly not an `ST` sort of task.  @yanpas Can you please be more specific as to your actual goal?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson no goal, just wondering and getting minuses

Comment: People are just offended by your assumptions about monads and then probably started collectively not to tell you about unsafe IO (which, I believe, most people know). Btw. the constructor of every monad is `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` in `System.IO.Unsafe` (base).

Use it with caution and read the description in the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html) carefully.

Comment: “Use it with caution” – that's too weak. The correct advice is _**don't** use it_ in general Haskell code, only for wrappers around foreign-function calls (i.e. C functions which can be wrapped to something properly pure, which the C language can't by itself guarantee). _Sometimes_ it can also make sense to use `unsafePerformIO` in Haskell itself, as a last-resort optimisation, but this should almost never be necessary (`ST` can do most of the operations you might need for this). Any function you can write in Haskell at all can also be written completely without IO, at worst it'll be slower.

Comment: @leftaroundabout perhaps you might want to submit a patch for the documentation then, because the docs don't say it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, there are some rather interesting use-cases for `unsafePerformIO` that I'd be sad to lose. Off the top of my head: 1. Running (conceptually pure) parallel computations. 2. Data structures designed around a generalization of laziness, where nodes in the structure are replaced by semantically equivalent but "improved" versions. See "Simple confluently persistent catenable lists" by Kaplan, Okasaki, and Tarjan (particularly Section 2) for a discussion of this technique.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is

#### No, you can't!

<sup>Well, *yes*, GHC has a thing called `unsafePerformIO`, but this is *not* part of the Haskell standard, merely a hack to allow certain “morally pure” functions from other languages to be called using the foreign function interface, and reflect the type of those functions with the type they would have if you'd written them straight in pure Haskell.</sup>

Note that “unwrapping the `IO` monad” would *not* simply give you the result of that computation. If `IO` were a public-constructors type, it would actually look (conceptually) something like the following:

```
data IO' a =
    WriteToFile FilePath String
  | PutStr String
  | WithStdLine (String -> IO' a)
  | ...
  | SequenceIO (IO' ()) (IO' a)
```

Pattern matching on such an `IO' a` value would normally not give you access to anything of type `a`, it would merely give you some *description of actions to be performed*, and perhaps some function that could possibly yield an `a` value *from* intermediate results obtained from the environment.

The only way to actually get useful work done would then still be like it is now: by binding it to something like the `main` action, which then executed by some “real world entity” (the runtime).

If you want to implement an algorithm that describes a proper mathematical (i.e. pure) function but seems to lend itself to an imperative programming style with mutation etc., then you should not implement this in the `IO` monad at all. You might well be able to just implement it in ordinary pure Haskell98 by just choosing suitable data structures, or perhaps it makes sense to use [the `ST` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) to achieve e.g. array updates with the same performance they'd have in imperative languages.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to place some impure code inside pure functions?

- What if there **was** a way to do this?
- What if **everyone else** could use it?

Would you be willing to sit down and scrutinise the sources of ***each and every library and program*** you use to check they are safe?

If you are, then Haskell probably isn't for you - I suggest you have a look at languages like [Standard ML](https://www.smlnj.org/sml.html) or [OCaml](https://ocaml.org)...

---

You're still here?

Alright then, there's an alternative approach which you can use:

- abstract out the regular Haskell code from the effect-centric code, using plain ol' ordinary functions.

It's possible to do this because
functions are *first-class values* in Haskell - in particular, *functions can be used as arguments* e.g:

```
fmap  :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
```

As your powers of abstraction improve, you'll delegate more and more work to regular Haskell code (in the form of functions), with just a small cohort of definitions being tainted by effects (including `main :: IO ()`). It requires some extra effort to start with, but the long-term rewards are substantial...