# Haskell: How to make side effects in pure functions

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner and I feel trouble about how to present some side effects in some pure functions, i.e, a very easy `size` function...

```
size :: [Int] -> StateT Int IO ()
size = fmap (\x -> do 
                     num <- get
                     put (num + 1)
                   return x)    -- some pseudo code like this...
```

I know there're lots of errors... the `return` which I mean this lambda returns `x` itself so that the list's values may not be changed... In fact, I want to use `StateT` to present some side effect. How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that `fmap`?

Comment: @arrowd In order to traverse all elements, in fact, I am only testing the usage of `StateT` monad

Comment: Try looking up `traverse`. The documentation says "Map each element of a structure to an action, evaluate these actions from left to right, and collect the results".

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522491/is-there-a-way-to-place-some-impure-code-inside-pure-functions .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, at this point in the learning process you probably shouldn't be worrying about "side effects". Also you're trying to mix two monads, `State` and `IO`, at a point where you don't seem to have mastered either. So you probably should take it easier.

It is possible to perform stateful actions within the `IO` monad using `IORefs`, which you can think of as mutable variables. If I were you I wouldn't go there just yet. Then there is the `State` monad which, roughly speaking, is a handy way of *simulating* stateful functions in a pure setting.

In theory, you can think of a stateful function `f :: a -> b` as a pure function of type `f :: (a,s) -> (b,s)`, where `s` represents some state which you can access and change. The above doesn't quite fit the monad framework, because in a monad `m` we want `a -> m b` to represent effectful functions from `a` to `b`. But it's easy to adapt. The type  `(a,s) -> (b,s)` can be uncurried to obtain  `a -> s -> (b,s)` and we take `m b` to be `s -> (b,s)`, so `a -> m b` represents `a -> s -> (b,s)`.

So this is what the monad `State s` represents. For every type `b` the type `State s b` is `s -> (b,s)`, which can be read as saying "give me the missing initial state `s` so I can compute a `b` and a final state `s`. And a stateful function `a -> State s b` is `a -> s -> (b,s)`, which can be read as saying "this function takes an `a` and produces a computation which given an initial state `s` produces a result `b` and a final state `s`.

This is just to give you a rough idea of how it works. Now here's some code that does what you want. Let's start with a simple approach.

```
size :: [Int] -> State Int ()
size []     = put 0
size (x:xs) = do size xs
                 num <- get 
                 put (num + 1)
```

The type is `State Int ()` because you are simply updating an integer state and returning no value (the state is all we care about).

The procedure is very similar to a usual recursive function for calculating size (without accumulator), but we do the work by updating state. To run this example just do,

```
runState (size list) 0
```

for some `list`. Note the `0` which is the initial state is irrelevant here, because the algorithm works by setting the state as `0` for the empty list then adding `1` for each element.

Now a version that works in an accumulating fashion,

```
sizeAc :: [Int] -> State Int ()
sizeAc []     = return ()
sizeAc (x:xs) = do num <- get 
                   put (num + 1)
                   sizeAc xs
```

Again to run this example just do,

```
runState (sizeAc list) 0
```

Note in this case you must use `0` as the initial state. What the function does is, for each element of the list it updates the state by adding one to the state's value. For an empty list it does nothing.

Finally a version with `map`, since it appears in your initial attempt. First we implement the counting action.

```
count :: State Int ()
count = do num <- get 
           put (num + 1)
```

This action consists of accessing the state and updating it with an added unit. Then build a list of such actions for each element in the list.

```
sizeAux'   :: [Int] -> [State Int ()]
sizeAux' xs = map (\x -> count) xs
```

Note the type of the result is a list. The result is a list where all elements are the action `count`. Then we execute those actions in sequence, using `sequence_`, whose type is as below (specialised to lists and to our particular monad).

```
 sequence_ :: [m a] -> m ()
 sequence_ :: [State Int ()] -> State Int ()
```

The resulting function is

```
size'   :: [Int] -> State Int ()
size' xs = sequence_ (sizeAux' xs)
```

Which again can be run via,

```
runState (size' list) 0
```

and note again here the initial state `0` is essential.

This might still feel somewhat complicated at this point. You'll need to have a better understanding of the monad class, the do notation and the particularities of the State monad. In any case this is where you should be heading, not mixing State with IO.

Answer (score 3):

For programmers coming from an imperative world, I think the most familiar answers are `for` and `for_`. Example:

```
import Data.Foldable

size :: [Int] -> StateT Int IO ()
size xs = for_ xs $ \x -> do             -- similar to "for x in xs do ..."
   num <- get
   -- IO example:
   lift $ putStrLn $ "Now incrementing " ++ num
   put (num + 1)
```

The above code as a side effect increments the `Int` state, but eventually returns a boring dummy value `()`. If we wanted to return the last `Int` state as well, we need to use:

```
size :: [Int] -> StateT Int IO Int   -- return Int instead of ()
size xs = do
   for_ xs $ \x -> do
      num <- get
      lift $ putStrLn $ "Now incrementing " ++ num
      put (num + 1)
   get  -- return the last state
```

(Also note that the above will not compute the size/length if the initial `Int` state is not `0`. I'm not sure about why you are using a `StateT Int IO` here.)

That being said, note that in Haskell we tend to avoid using side effects (even nicely wrapped in a monad like above) when we can avoid it. It is usually much better to keep code free from side effects, when possible.

```
size :: [Int] -> Int
size = length
-- or
size = foldl' (\ s _ -> s+1) 0
```

If you are a beginner, perhaps tinkering with monads and monad transformers is not the best way to start. I would recommend to learn the basics first (algebraic data types, pattern matching, recursion, higher order functions, ...), then moving to monads / functors / applicatives (e.g. `State Int`, not `StateT Int IO`), and then finally move to transformers (`StateT Int IO`).