# Haskell state monad different behaviour on even and odd function calls

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I want to make a funciton that adds 5 on odd calls and subtracts 6 on even calls using state monads.

```
f 5 =  10
f 7 = 1
f 4 = 9
f 2 = -4
```

0 is even so f 5 adds 5.
1 is odd so f 7 subtracts 6 and so on.

What I have now:

```
data Parity = Even | Odd deriving (Show, Eq)

not' :: Parity -> Parity
not' Even = Odd
not' Odd = Even

isOdd :: Int -> State Parity Int
isOdd x = state $ \(p) -> (if p == Odd then x + 5 else x - 6, not' p)

g n = do isOdd n

apply n = runState (g n) Even
```

I tried writing it like that, but everytime 'apply' is used the state is not saved.
It only add 5 because of the even at the end.
How do I make it save the state and only initalize it once and not every time ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I rewrote it as a question.

Comment: You can give an example to show what you want. by the way, your code has syntax error at  `(p) -> (if p == Odd then x + 5 else ...`, it should be `\p->(if...)`

Comment: I fixed it now.

Comment: You cannot keep the state after `runState` has been called. That means that you can put all the code need state tranformer within a function, say, `stateFoo` and do the computation, for example, `do n1 <- g n; n2 <- g n1; .. ; return nk`  and then `runState stateFoo`  to get the result.

Comment: statefoo x= runstate (do n <- g x return n) doesn't work, no instace show...

Comment: Try `statefoo = do n1<-g 5; n2 <-g 7; n3<-g 4; n4<-g 2; return [n1, n2, n3, n4]` and then `runState statefoo Odd`

Comment: So you cannot run the function on an arbitrary input but have to predefine n1 n2 etc?

Comment: No, you can arbitrary design the `statefoo` function with arbitrary augument, here is an example: `statefoo x = do n1<-g x; n2<-g n1; n3<-g n2; n4<-g n3; return [n1, n2, n3, n4]`; `runState (statefoo 5) Odd`. Just a demo, comment cannot show complex coding. you can do this with recurrsive function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447330/haskell-how-to-make-side-effects-in-pure-functions/53448409#53448409) I wrote a few days ago may be helpful. 
Keeping it short, `State s` is just a convenient way of simulating "stateful functions" `f :: a -> b` as pure functions `f :: (a,s) -> (b,s)`. To fit the monad framework though these are curried, so (roughly) of the form `f :: a -> s -> (b,s)`.

The type `State s b` is roughly `s -> (b,s)`, which can be read as "a computation that returns a value `b` and a final state `s` and that requires an initial state `s` to be run". A monadic function `a -> State s b` is therefore a function that takes an input `a`, and that can be run given an initial state `s`, to produce a value `b` and a final state `s`.

Your function `isOdd` is,

```
isOdd x :: Int -> State Parity Int
isOdd x = state $ \p -> (if p == Odd then x + 5 else x - 6, not' p)
```

which is roughly,

```
isOdd' x :: Int -> Parity -> (Int,Parity)
isOdd' x p = (if p == Odd then x + 5 else x - 6, not' p)
```

And your call,

```
 apply n = runState (isOdd n) Even
```

is roughly,

```
 apply' n = isOdd' x Even
```

That's all. You are essentially calculating

```
 apply' n = --definition of apply'
            isOdd' n Even
            -- definition of isOdd'
            (\x p -> (if p == Odd then x + 5 else x - 6, not' p)) n Even
            -- application to the arguments `n` and `Even` 
            = (if Even == Odd then n + 5 else n - 6, not' Even)
            -- simplifying
            = (n - 6, Odd)
```

so,

```
apply' n = (n - 6, Odd)
```

Here is an example of how to sequence your function properly,

```
f :: Int -> State Parity Int
f n = isOdd n >>= (\x -> isOdd x)
```

or equivalently

```
f :: Int -> State Parity Int
f n = do x <- isOdd n
         isOdd x
```

When you run it via e.g. `apply n = runState (f n) Even` you are first running `isOdd n Even`, to obtain a result `m` and a new final state which will be `False`, and then running `isOdd m False`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the an answer, how can you print the result of f n?

Comment: You don't :) Note the type of `f n` is the same as that of `isOdd`, i.e. `State Parity Int`. You don't print `f n`, instead you run it with an initial state, `runState (f n) Even`