# Output in middle of function

Tags: haskell

How can you output something in the middle of a function but still return something other than IO ()?

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = do
    print n
    n + 1
```

thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522491/is-there-a-way-to-place-some-impure-code-inside-pure-functions .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` consumes an Int; it produces an IO action

```
f n = print n >> return ( n + 1) :: IO Int
```

Answer (score 8):

For *debugging purposes only*, you can use the the `trace` function. If you really want to produce output, use `IO`.

```
import Debug.Trace

f :: Int -> Int
f n = trace (show n) (n + 1)
```

`trace` is essentially an impure function that writes its argument to standard error and returns the identity function.

To do this properly, using `IO`, change the type to `Int -> IO Int`.

```
f :: Int -> IO Int
f n = do
    print n
    return (n + 1)
```

Comment: How would you use `IO` and return an `Int` at the same time? Not for debugging

Comment: You mean, have a function with type `Int -> IO Int`?

Comment: @w1220 you can't. Once you've got an `IO` value, you can't get back to a non-`IO` one. This is by design - any `IO` effects make a function/value impure, and this needs to be reflected in the type signature. If you described your actual problem, we might be able to help you figure out how to do it in Haskell.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I had the same thought "this is a FAQ", but apparently the OP has no issues with the `IO` part in `IO ()`, but dislikes the `()` part since they want to return a `Int`. So, `IO Int` is the answer.

Comment: Note to future readers wondering *why* `trace` is "for debugging purposes only" and why you shouldn't use it in your program: you'll change a different part of your program and suddenly you'll find that your `trace` is printing several times or not at all.