# Haskell gloss library, how to run appendFile on model signiture for log to file?

Tags: haskell, simulate, gloss

this is the bouncing ball code. I'm trying to make 'appendFile' run on the update function, so when the ball bounces off the wall, then 'appendFile' will write the px and px values to the file "log.txt"

```
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Data.ViewPort (ViewPort)

main :: IO ()
main =
  simulate
    (InWindow "Bouncing ball" (width, height) (50, 50))
    white
    30
    initial
    view
    update
```

but I'm having trouble because 'appendFile' only runs on signiture IO. And I don't know how to apply it in a situation like this

```
update :: ViewPort -> Float -> World -> World
update _ _ World {position = (px, py), velocity = (vx, vy)} =

  let 
      appendFile "Log.txt" ("" ++ show px ++ " " + show py ++ "")
      newPx = px + vx
      newPy = py + vy
      newVx = if newPx >= fromIntegral width || newPx <= 0 then - vx else vx
      newVy = if newPy >= fromIntegral height || newPy <= 0 then - vy else vy
   in World {position = (newPx, newPy), velocity = (newVx, newVy)}
```

Comment: I would use [``trace``](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) and redirect the error output to the log. You can try: ``newPx = trace ("" ++ show px ++ " " + show py ++ "") (px + vx)``.

Comment: but how to save it into a file?

Comment: I have upvoted your question because I would also be interested in it. I work in Linux and run the program like this: main 2>> /tmp/log.txt. In Windows, it might look [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/language-compilers/redirecting-error-command-prompt): main.exe 2>&Log.txt.

Comment: You can also change `update :: ViewPort -> Float -> World -> World` -> `update :: ViewPort -> Float -> World -> (String,World)` and write the text in the `simulate` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522491/is-there-a-way-to-place-some-impure-code-inside-pure-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell is really strict about side effects. Writing to a file is a side effect, and a pure function (like your `update`) is not allowed to have side effects.

If you merely want to record the data for debugging then you can use the infamous accursed [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html), which provides a back door into the IO monad for pure computations. The reason for the "unsafe" bit of the name is that this makes no promises about how often the IO action gets run, or even if it gets run at all.

BUT the code you have above won't actually call `appendFile`. In fact that is a syntax error; a `let` introduces values which might be used in the code, but you have no assignment for the result of `appendFile`.

You would need something more like:

```
let
   ... omitted
in seq 
    (unsafePerformIO $ appendFile "Log.txt" (show px ++ " " ++ show py ++ "\n")
    World {position = (newPx, newPy), velocity = (newVx, newVy)}
```

`seq` is a magic function which is "strict" in its first argument, so the `unsafePerformIO` gets evaluated before the new `World`, even though nothing ever uses the result of that first argument.

However **this is a kluge**. You should not use `unsafePerformIO` for production code. It is a [lie to the compiler](https://www.azquotes.com/quote/1196945). If you make a habit of it then the compiler *will* get its revenge, and it will not be pretty.

If this is for production code then you should instead use [`simulateIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.13.2.1/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Simulate.html). This takes an update function which returns an `IO` value, so then you can write `update` to return an `IO World` and everyone will be happy.